Issue with AJAX Request Triggering Unrelated Method in PHP
I am trying to update the like/upvote button. For that I have created a menthod[Method named: likepost()] in my Controller named Posts. Here is the code for my method.
public function likepost() 
{
  if (IsloggedIn()) {
      // Check if the request is a POST request
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
          $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
          $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; // Assuming the user is logged in and we are storing the user ID in session
  
          // Check if the user already liked this post
          if ($this->postModel->hasUserLikedPost($post_id, $user_id)) {
              // User has already liked the post, so we need to remove the like
              if ($this->postModel->removeLike($post_id, $user_id)) {
                  // Decrease the like count in the posts table
                  $this->postModel->decrementLikeCount($post_id);
                  echo json_encode(['status' => 'unliked', 'likes_count' => $this->postModel->getLikesCount($post_id)]);
              }
          } else {
              // User has not liked the post, so we add the like
              if ($this->postModel->addLike($post_id, $user_id)) {
                  // Increase the like count in the posts table
                  $this->postModel->incrementLikeCount($post_id);
                  echo json_encode(['status' => 'liked', 'likes_count' => $this->postModel->getLikesCount($post_id)]);
              }
          }
      } else {
          echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Invalid request']);
      }
  } else {
      echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'User not logged in']);
  }
}

Following is the code for my Model:
        public function hasUserLikedPost($user_id, $post_id) {
          echo $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM post_likes WHERE user_id = :user_id AND post_id = :post_id');
          $this->db->bind(':user_id', $user_id);
          $this->db->bind(':post_id', $post_id);
          $row = $this->db->single();
          
          return $row ? true : false;
      }
      
      public function addLike($post_id, $user_id) {
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO post_likes (post_id, user_id) VALUES (:post_id, :user_id)');
        $this->db->bind(':post_id', $post_id);
        $this->db->bind(':user_id', $user_id);
        return $this->db->execute();
      }
    
      public function removeLike($post_id, $user_id) {
        $this->db->query('DELETE FROM post_likes WHERE post_id = :post_id AND user_id = :user_id');
        $this->db->bind(':post_id', $post_id);
        $this->db->bind(':user_id', $user_id);
        return $this->db->execute();
      }
    
      public function incrementLikeCount($post_id) {
        $this->db->query('UPDATE posts SET likes_count = likes_count + 1 WHERE id = :post_id');
        $this->db->bind(':post_id', $post_id);
        return $this->db->execute();
      }
    
      public function decrementLikeCount($post_id) {
        $this->db->query('UPDATE posts SET likes_count = likes_count - 1 WHERE id = :post_id');
        $this->db->bind(':post_id', $post_id);
        return $this->db->execute();
      }
    
    public function getLikesCount($post_id) {
      $this->db->query('SELECT likes_count FROM posts WHERE id = :post_id');
      $this->db->bind(':post_id', $post_id);
      return $this->db->single()->likes_count;
    }

Here is my view code:
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="upvote" data-post-id='<?php echo $data['post']->id; ?>'>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Upvote <span id="display"><?php echo $data['post']->likes_count; ?></span>
  </button>

Following is my AJAX query written in my main.js
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      let btn = document.getElementById("upvote");
      if (!btn) {
        console.error('Element with ID "upvote" not found');
        return;
    }
      let disp = document.getElementById("display");
      let post_id = btn.getAttribute("data-post-id");
    
      btn.onclick = function () {
          // Create an AJAX request to send the post_id to PHP
          let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open("POST", "<?php echo URLROOT;?>/posts/likepost", true);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                  // Handle the response from PHP
                  let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                  if (response.status === 'liked') {
                      disp.innerHTML = response.likes_count; // Update the like count
                  } else if (response.status === 'unliked') {
                      disp.innerHTML = response.likes_count; // Update the like count
                  }
              }
          };
    
          // Send the post_id as part of the request
          xhr.send("post_id=" + post_id);
      }
    });

Whenever i am trying to run this i am getting following error in my console:


As per this error it is showing error in my another method which is running fine, i am pasting that here for reference as well:
    public function show($id)
        {
                $post = $this->postModel->getPostById($id);
                $user = $this->userModel->getUserById($post->userid);
                $data = [
                'post' => $post,
                'user' => $user,   
                ];
                $this->view('posts/show',$data);
        }


So it seem that xhr.responseText isn't JSON as expected; if you look in the Network tab, what's actually returned? Does the request sent in the network tab look as you'd expect?

I suspect that your search for a post with id = $id failed, and you got back “false” instead of a post.

Thanks mykaf and James , I have fixed the issues. I have passed the userid after the upvote button is clicked and also have fixed the URL i was pasig in request in php format.

I think @James is right. Basically : in the show($id), the value of $post is not the object you are expecting from the DB, it is false.
And when you try to read the property userid from false instead of an object, it gives you this error.
There are some things to check :

Make sure let post_id = btn.getAttribute("data-post-id"); gets you exactly the post_id you expect and is correctly sent
There is one check missing here because I don't see the code but simply just check the post_id sent from xhr is the good one when it arrives to show($id)
Check in the method show($id) that $id is a valid value (not "" or 0 or false for example)
If the value of $id is correct, check the method $this->postModel->getPostById() does correctly its job
Finally check if the value of $id exists in your database if there is still the problem (if it doesn't, you have a problem somewhere else)

I think you'll be able to solve your problem with that.

The first issue here is your returning HTML not JSON data, so the error is related to your code trying to parse the HTML into a JSON array, which is not right.
Either change your javascript to reflect that you are responding with HTML or if that is a mistake, make sure your response is correct JSON.
I can also see from your inspect that the page you are testing has a PHP error, this might be related to the JSON issue if the same error is being spat out just before the JSON data, you can check this by looking at the XHR requests tab and you should be able to see your ajax request and response data.

Where do you see OP actually returning HTML then? OP is using echo json_encode - This is not the issue

The OP has literally screenshotted the console error which says unexpected "" both of which are HTML being output either before or after the JSON.

That's because of the warning produced by the code (and not error), not by OP actually sending back HTML... This answer doesn't make any sense at all. FWIW: The actual issue was already provided by James in the comment section

in fact my answer does mention that it could be the PHP error (warning) being output as well as the JSON, and it is very relevant and is an issue, if that is not fixed the JavaScript cannot parse the JSON response.
